# Proof for the relation between arctan and log

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having problems to prove that $\arctan{z} = \frac{i}{2}\log\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}$ , for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ . Can someone show me how to demonstrate that??

Comment: Apply exponential $e^x$ to both sides and you get Euler's circle relation.

Comment: Use partial fractions decomposition (complex linear terms) on $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ and integrate. See what happens...

Comment: use the power series expansion.

Comment: Oh come on guys, this question doesn't deserve to be closed so quickly.  It doesn't appear to be a duplicate and is what I would think to be a "question within the scope defined in the help center".  Do you guys even read the help center?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam That is not a recommended path IMO

Comment: Differentiate both sides for the easy method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z=\tan(w)$ so that $w=\arctan(z)$.  Then using Euler's Formula, we can write

$$\begin{align}
z&=-i\left(\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{e^{iw}+e^{-iw}}\right) \\\\
&=-i\left(\frac{1-e^{-i2w}}{1+e^{-i2w}}\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

It is straightforward to solve $(1)$ for $e^{-i2w}$ and reveals

$$e^{-i2w}=\frac{1-iz}{1+iz} \tag 2$$

Next, we take the complex logarithm of both sides and divide by $i2$ obtain

$$\arctan(z)=\frac i2\log\left(\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right)$$

as was to be shown!

---

> **SPECIAL NOTE:**  Inasmuch as the complex logarithm is multi-valued, the complex arctangent is likewise.

Comment: I think its perfectly fine.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

Method $1$:

> See that they are equal for $x=0$.  See that the derivatives are equal.  Basically same argument as method $3$ backwards.  Is also equivalent to taking the power series expansion of both sides by using Taylor's theorem.

---

Method $2$:

$$\log\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}=\log(1-iz)-\log(1+iz)$$

Assuming $z\in\mathbb R$ so that this method will work and so that $\arctan(x)$ is defined.

$$\log(x)=\log|x|+i\arg(x),\ x\in\mathbb C\tag{Identity from Euler's formula}$$

---

$$\log(1-iz)=\log|1-iz|+i\arg(1-iz)\\=\log\sqrt{1+z^2}+i\arg(1-iz)$$

Similarly,

$$\log(1+iz)=\log\sqrt{1+z^2}+i\arg(1+iz)$$

Thus,

$$\require{cancel}\log(1-iz)-\log(1+iz)=\left[\cancel{\log\sqrt{1+z^2}}+i\arg(1-iz)\right]-\left[\cancel{\log\sqrt{1+z^2}}+i\arg(1+iz)\right]$$

$$=i[\arg(1-iz)-\arg(1+iz)]$$

Now, under the assumption $z\in\mathbb R$, we can draw this:

[image]

See that their arguments are equal but in opposite directions so that we may establish the following relationship:

$$-\arg(1-iz)=\arg(1+iz)$$

and substituting this in,

$$=-2i\arg(1+iz)$$

Put this back into our original problem

$$\arctan(z)=\frac i2(-2i\arg(1+iz))=\arg(1+iz)$$

It does not require very much trigonometry to see that

$$z=\tan(\arg(1+iz))$$

---

See then that for $z\in\mathbb R$, $\arctan(z)$ and $\log\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}$ are analytic, and so by analytic continuation, they are equal for $z\in\mathbb C$.

---

Method $3$:

See that

$$\arctan(x)=\int_0^x\frac1{1+u^2}du$$

But also that

$$\int_0^x\frac1{1+u^2}du=\frac12\int_0^x\frac1{1-iu}+\frac1{1+iu}dx\\=\frac i2\log\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}$$

Thus, they are equivalent.

Comment: Crossing out terms in mathjax, I need to take note of that...+1

Comment: @imranfat Many neat things in the [Handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Take note that crossing out terms can be done in different ways too.  For example: $\cancelto0{x+5}$